# using img and glyphicon in js

Tags: javascript, html

I am not able to display the glyphicon-trash image using java script. I see a broken rectangle image.[image]

```
var $tmp;
...

$tmp=$("<img id = "myId" src='' <i class'glyphicon glyphicon-trash' title='Delete'></i>/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest `<i>` into  instead of `<img>` without closing tag.

```
"<div id = 'myId'> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' title='Delete'></i></div>"
```

Comment: `"<div id='myId'>...` with apostrophes if at all because if you use quotes for id, they match with opening quote of the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Glyphicons don't require img. Also what you did is not how you nest tags within each other, and your quotes are kinda mismatched.

Try this:

```
$tmp = $("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' title='Delete'></i>");
```